# How can I provide a photo or video when a webpage requests access to camera?

Tags: browser, camera, media

I am curious if there is an extension or something for Firefox, Chrome, or any other browser, which would allow me to pick a photo or video instead of really turning on the camera, when browser requests access to the camera (and for photo it would then convert it to like a 10 second static video stream and then "turn off" camera and for video it would play it and then at the end it would "turn off" camera).

I am asking because I find again and again legitimate uses of this. For example, site asks for passport image to be shown to the camera, and I have it on my disk, so instead of trying to find my passport, I could just have an image/video I would pick. Or my bank supports paying an invoice by showing a QR code with camera to the website, but I get a QR code as PDF invoice. Now I would have to print a digital invoice to paper to be able to show it as QR code back to the website. Nonsense.

I know of `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` CLI argument in Chrome, but I would like something user friendly, where I can just pick files during regular browsing.

Comment: Use some fake webcam software?

Comment: Answering this post amounts to a method for identity theft.

Comment: Check the duplicate for virtual camera tools such as OBS Virtual Camera. Additionally many people have Smartphones these days that can view emails, pictures and Web pages and could achieve the same result without having to print things.